# Aggregating counter metric from a Prometheus exporter that doesn't respect monotonicity

Tags: prometheus, promql

We have a system with a Prometheus exporter. It exposes a counter metric. However, the exporter sometimes misbehaves and breaks monotonicity like this:

- T1: X
- T2: X + 1
- T3: X

Example:

[image: Graph of counter misbehaving]

As a result, when applying `rate()` or `increase()` on the counter, we get huge spikes, because Prometheus understands that the counter was reset to 0, and then increased again. So we get increases series like:

- T1: 0
- T2: 1
- T3: X

X can be in the thousands, so this completely messes with the aggregated metrics.

Example of `increase(metric[3d])`:

[image: Graph of increase() on counter that misbehaves]

Do you have any idea of how could we work around this wrong values with native PromQL? For simplicity, let's assume that the errors are always in the form of X/X+1/X.

I've thought of using delta() as if this metric were a gauge, but we can't do that, because in some scenarios it actually resets to 0 as counters normally do, and delta() won't understand it.

Fixing the exporter is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

`increase()` function in Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to gracefully handle small spikes in counter metrics. Possible workaround is to use [delta()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#delta) function instead of [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase), and filter out negative values when the counter resets or goes down after the spike:

```
delta(metric[5m]) > 0
```

But this method doesn't work properly for long lookbehind windows in square brackets. In this case the query can return long gaps and too small values on long time ranges after counter reset.

Fortunately, there is an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring solution, which gracefully handles cases with counters with possible spikes - VictoriaMetrics (I'm the core developer of VictoriaMetrics). Its [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) and [rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) functions handle such spikes in an expected way by ignoring small counter decreases.

Additionally, VictoriaMetrics provides [remove_resets](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#remove_resets) function, which can be used for removing resets from counter metrics.

Comment: Interesting. I knew little about VM and thought that it had an identical implementation of the logic. It may be useful to explicitly add to the answer the link to the Medium post that is mentioned in the docs about the compatibility differences: https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e